# Disable or Hide Some Parent Class Functions in C++

Tags: c++

I notice that there there maybe different ways to disable or hide some class member functions inherited from the parent class.

For example, given the following base class:

```
class Foo {
public: 
    void funcA() {}
};
```

#### <del>Option 1</del>

```
class Bar : public Foo {
private:
     Foo::funcA;
};
```

(Edit: I notice later one that **Option 1** will have error under `clang`: "ISO C++11 does not allow access declarations; use using declaration instead")

#### Option 2

```
class Bar : public Foo {
private:
     using Foo::funcA; 
};
```

#### Option 3

```
class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    void funcA() = delete; 
};
```

Which is the better way to do it? Or are they equally the same?

---

Before you try doing this, please read comments below by @JeffCoffin et. al:

> The fact that you want to disable or hide something from the parent class tends to indicate that you probably shouldn't have used it as a parent class to start with

Comment: The fact that you want to disable or hide something from the parent class *tends* to indicate that you probably shouldn't have used it as a parent class to start with.

Comment: Option 4: Wrap that class without inheritance (any attempt to disable a parent function is unsafe, the function is still accessible after a conversion (cast) to the base class).

Comment: I think your design is at fault. Perhaps a rethink

Comment: Is option one is valid C++ I wonder?

Comment: @AngelusMortis, honestly, I am not sure either and could not find a good reference about this.

Comment: @YuchenZhong Then how did you came up with that option?

Comment: @AngelusMortis, this is long story. It was during one of the code review. I have summited code with option 2 and the team lead suggests that `using` is redundant and I should remove that. And then I notice it doesn't build on a different compiler.

Comment: @AngelusMortis, overall, I don't think this is a very good design either. I should come up with a better strategy here.

Comment: I having a similar issue:
When specializing one of my classes to handle an specific type, but only that type, I found that I want to hide the three types from the base class, so I need to hide them, I think the Option 2 is a good way to do it.

Comment: Hey @PatricioRossi, that's interesting. But as suggested in other comments above, you should probably move these properties out of the base class.

Comment: @Yuchen Zhong some times you cannot do that, I will paste simple example bellow.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue but instead of trying to hide methods of Foo in its children, I instead made a _BaseFoo class that had all the functionality ALL the child classes would have in common. Then I made the Foo a child of this _BaseFoo, and made the new specialized classes children of _BaseFoo also (really wasn't called Foo btw).

Answer (score 5):

The three options are not the same. For the first two I'm not sure if there is any real difference(I cannot test them as I don't have a computer, but I think they're the same). But the third one is definitely different - it **erases** the method. Thus in the third case you wouldn't be able to call that method from other methods of the class, whereas in the first two cases you would be able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you just need to hide some Methods from the base class, and you cannot remove them, imagine that you have something like this:

```
/**
 * Draws elements
 */
class Type1 {/*class contents*/}
/**
 * Handle Input
 */
class Type2 : public Type1 {/*class contents*/}
/**
 * Handle Very special input
 */
class Type3 : public Type2 {/*class contents*/}

class BasePools {

public:

        BasePools(/*some initialization here*/);

        /* some generic functionality methods here, and pure virtual ones */
        void blah();
        virtual blah2() = 0;
        virtual ~BasePools();

        // just as example some setters
        void add(Type1* newElement) {/* adds element to pool: Type1*/}
        void add(Type2* newElement) {/* adds element to pools: Type2 and Type1*/}
        void add(Type3* newElement) {/* adds element to pools: Type3, Type2 and Type1 here*/}

protected:

        void handleType1() {/* do something with Type1 pool elements */}
        void handleType2() {/* do something with Type2 pool elements */}
        void handleType3() {/* do something with Type3 pool elements */}

// control pools.
        vector<Type1*> poolType1;
        vector<Type2*> poolType2;
        vector<Type3*> poolType3;
}

class SpecialType2 : public Type2 {/*extends Type2 */}

/**
 * Class that uses SpecialType2 only but needs access to the pools and methods.
 */
class SomeSpecialContainer : public BasePools {

public: 

        using BasePools::BasePools;

        // only allow this type.
        void add(SpecialType2* newElement) {/* adds element to pools: Type2 and Type1*/}

protected:

        // hide defaul adders.
        using BasePools::add;
}
```

As you can see SomeSpecialContainer will only handle SpecialType2 and hide the other base types.

Comment: Can you not move the method `void add` out of the `BasePools` and put them into a `GenericContainer` that derived from `BasePools`?

Comment: Imagine that the vectors are private (in my case they are but not in the example) and there are also more shared methods that uses the vectors.

Comment: Well, that's fair enough. It was more or less the same situation for me when I had to do something like this cuz I was using a 3rd party library ...

Comment: Yes, the ideal scenario some times is not there, specially when you are working on already working code that you cannot change, and in that cases this little tricks come handily!